# Fragment transaction is lagging

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-webview, fragmenttransaction, bottomnavigationview

I use a `BottomNavigationView` for switching between fragments. The problem is that my first `view` has a `webview` included which is quite CPU heavy. I implemented a caching mechanism which holds my fragments in the backstack. Whenever i switch to a fragment, my app searches for the fragment and if it is not initialized, it creates a new one. So when i switch from the first to the second fragment or vice versa, my transaction animation is not really shown and it lags a bit.

Do you have any idea how I can make it perform better, or how I can prevent the lag, and make a smooth transition between those fragments?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about visual delay, you could postpone the webview's loading with

```
webview.postDelayed({
    //loading goes in here
},200)
```